# Quantum Zeno Effect

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, probability

This is a *homework exercise* that is very useful to think about:

A quantum system of two levels is described by two unitary vectors on $\mathscr{H}=\mathbb{C}^2$. The initial state of the system is

$$ \mid\psi (0) \rangle =\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}.\tag{1}$$
The hamiltonian of the system is $H=\varepsilon \sigma_z$, where $\varepsilon>0$ is a constant with energy units and $\sigma_z$ the Pauli matrix
$$\sigma_z \equiv \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 \end{pmatrix}.\tag{2}$$
I know, resolving the Schrödinger equation, which is the wave function $\mid\psi (t)\rangle$ in a time $t$:
$$ \mid\psi(t)\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} \text{ e}^{-\text{i} \varepsilon t/\hbar}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} \text{ e}^{\text{i} \varepsilon t/\hbar}\equiv  \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \mid\uparrow\rangle \text{ e}^{-\text{i} \varepsilon t/\hbar}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \mid \downarrow \rangle \text{ e}^{\text{i} \varepsilon t/\hbar}.\tag{3}$$
If we measure the energy we can obtain
$E_\uparrow = \varepsilon $ with a probability of $$ p_\uparrow[1] = \dfrac{1}{2}.\tag{4}$$
and $E_\downarrow =-\varepsilon$ with a probability of
$$p_\downarrow [1] =\dfrac{1}{2}\tag{5}$$
where the braket $[\cdot ]$ means the times the particle has been measured. Now we measure the observable $\sigma_x$ in  regular intervals of time $t=\Delta t, 2 \Delta t, ..., N\Delta t$ ¿Where is the probability of obtaining the result $+1$ on the $N$ measurements? Study the probability of $+1$ when $\Delta t \rightarrow 0$ and $N \rightarrow \infty$ very large being the total time of the measurement finite $\tau\equiv N\Delta t$. Draw the probability function of $\tau$ for $\Delta t =1$ fs $=10^{-15}$ s and $\varepsilon=10^{-3}$ eV and discuss the physic relevance of the  previous limit.

> My answer is $$p_\uparrow [N] = 1-\dfrac{1}{2^N}\tag{6}$$ (binomial distribution ¿and the limit is Poisson distribution?)
>
> and the reduction of state vector $\textbf{R}$ is permanent, so $$p_\uparrow [\infty]=p_\uparrow [1]=\dfrac{1}{2}.\tag{7}$$

[image: "El camino a la realidad", Roger Penrose, p.714, Debate (2006)]
*El camino a la realidad*, Roger Penrose, p.714, Debate (2006)

**What is the correct answer? Am I wrong?**

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: What is the correct answer? Am I wrong?

Comment: 1. Next time, include *your actual question* in your post. 2. Check-my-work questions are frowned upon in this site (see the [site policies](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) )